# Sharing iCloud data between an iOS app and an OSX app with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

Tags: iphone, icloud

I've built an app that is intended to run (and share iCloud data) on both the iPhone and on Mac OSX. The two apps have different bundle identifiers (ending in `.iOS` and `.OSX` respectively), but I have set `Ubiquity Containers` in the iCloud settings to be the same:

[image]

Unfortunately, after synchronizing with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, it appears that data created on one device is not available on the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by editing the `.entitlements` file which was automatically created by XCode. In addition to the "ubiquity containers", there is a row in this file called "iCloud Key-Value Store" which can be modified to use the same bundle path. Once changed, I had to clean/rebuild both apps and viola! The data was shared.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by editing .entitlements file. make sure that "iCloud Key-Value Store" has same value in both the application.